# wpf populate list with combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I've been chasing SO for bits of information but not as a complete solution for my problem

I'm looking for a way to use a comboBox as a selector/filter for items that would be display in a listView,
where both comboBox and listView items has the same Enum properties (importance).

Later on I would like to add a checkbox property to the list, but first I want to achieve the first step.

My problem is that i'm getting kinda lost between definitions, and I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

**EDIT:**
I will try to clear my question:

I want to have a comboBox with items (from an Emun) that represent message importance (etc.       Regular, Important..).
When item is selected, all messages with that importance will be displayed.

I have this example which is purely code-based without any data binding.
[image: Example]

Comment: My problem is that I don't see how you would 1 list to "selector/filter" another identical list. Your question needs more details.

Comment: it is a little bit unclear what you are talking about. the defintions within xaml are rather good. try it with visual studio. http://www.wpftutorial.net/Controls.html "enum properties" maybe not the best term.

Comment: [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Comment: So where is the code that binds the `ComboBox` and `ListView`? It's pretty important to know how they are bound.

Comment: the question is still unclear try adding an example/image of what you are trying to achieve should look like

Comment: So, you would like to select a value in a combobox, and then filter your listbox to show only the items where a certain field matches the selected combobox value?  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I was able to bind the list with ObservableCollection, but I have no idea how to filter the results

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Thats what i'm asking for.

Comment: @MrKlin, so to be very clear, you're literally asking us to just mock up some example and write the code for you? I'm sorry, but Stackoverflow isn't the forum for that my friend. Get started and then come back with a specific problem and code to support it.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud -  That's really not my intention, i'm just asking for a lead to further look and learn myself, data-binding is pretty general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean you have a list of objects that have a property of a special type and you want to filter this list based on the value of the property. I also assume you are aware of the MVVM pattern that is commonly used to develop WPF applications:

Your viewmodel needs a property of the enum type. Lets call it `SelectedFilter`.
Your viewmodel needs a list of all existing enum values. Lets call that `AvailableFilters`.
Your viewmodel needs a list of all messages. Lets call it `Messages`.
Your viewmodel needs a list of some messages. Lets call it `FilteredMessages`.

Your ViewModel needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).

Your AvailableFilters are bound to the `ItemsSource` of your ComboBox.
Your SelectedFilter is bound to the `SelectedItem` of your ComboBox.
Your FilteredMessages is bound to the `ItemsSource` of your ListBox.

Any time your `SelectedFilter` changes, use LinQ (or a loop) to put only those `Messages` into `FilteredMessages` that fit. Make sure you signal NotifyPropertyChanged for `FilteredMessages` as well.

That was a lot of information in a short time, make sure you read some tutorials on `Data Binding in WPF`, `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `MVVM` if you feel you are uncertain what I'm talking about.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit overwhelmed :) going google some stuff now..

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would have a collection (observable) that contains all the items in the list.  Bind your combo box to a list of the enumeration values.  You will need to put a CollectionView on top of the Observable Collection.  As the enumeration changes in the combo box - you apply a new filter to the collection view source.  The UI that displays the filtered data should be bound to to the collection view source - not the observable collection.